# Look up dictionary by key (VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Sub Add(ByVal phone As String, ByVal name As String)
    MyBase.InnerHashtable.Add(phone, name)
End Sub

'--Subroutine to extract the value from a dictionary when the key is passed as input
Public Function Item(ByVal phone As String) As String
    Return CStr(MyBase.InnerHashtable.Item(phone))
End Function
```

SAMPLE ENTRIES:

```
'--Adding key and values to the dictionary    

 myDict.Add("6812036998", "Horton")
 myDict.Add("6812036999", "Olive")
```

I needed help for a reverse lookup on dictionary. Given the `key` I should be able to find the Name. However, my code below wont work as it is wrong.

```
Public Function lookupValue(ByVal name As String)
    Return CStr(MyBase.InnerHashtable.Item(name))
End Function
```

Comment: why would you want to find `name` in the `Dictionary` when already given the `name`. Or i suppose you want to find `name` when given the `key`?

Answer (score 1):

Values are not unique, so I guess you will need to use `LINQ` to get, say, the first value:

```
Dim myValue As String = myDict.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Value = "Horton").Key;
```

**Edit:**

As commented by both Alan Mathew and myself, please make sure to add `System.Linq` as one of your project reference and put `Imports System.Linq` in the file where you write the above line.

Comment: It isnt working. Says that FirstOrDefault method not present. Plus I need to generate a Function.

Comment: @AlanMathew updated. The previous syntax was for C# (my apologize). In order to make it work, you should go to your project reference and add System.Linq, also put import System.Linq on top of your .vb file

Comment: @AlanMathew : Make sure to put `Imports System.Linq` on top of your code file.

Comment: @AlanMathew makes sure you put the LINQ imports, also, it needs to use single `=` rather than double `==` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Ur code's identifier is key. But u need value as identifier. Try this
For each row as keyvaluepair (of string,string) in yourdictionary
if row.value=desiredstring then
Yourresult=row.key
End if

Next